# Given a vertex and 2 triangle height equations, get the equations, on which the triangle's sides lay

Tags: linear-algebra, triangles

One vertex of the triangle: $(3; -4)$

2 height equations:

$$
7x-2y-1=0
$$
$$
2x-7y-6=0
$$

The task is to find the straight line equations, on which the triangle sides lay.

So far, I haven't figured out how to proceed with this.

Also as I now made a comment, I did figure one point out: 
I do have a point, which isn't on any of the 2 given altitude equations, means that the vertex is on the 3rd altitude equation. The 2 altitude equations intersect eachother, which means I can make the third altitude equation by using 2 points and finding the intersection between the 2 equations.

Comment: What is a height equation? Your vertex is on neither of those lines so I (like you!) have no clue what it is you are supposed to be doing..

Comment: Under height I meant altitude. I'm not english so sort-of "direct" translations make some "goofy" stuff. And yes, I checked, the vertex is on neither of these equations. What I just figured out, is that I do have a point, which isn't on any of the 2 given altitude equations, means that the vertex is on the 3rd altitude equation. The 2 altitude equations intersect eachother, which means I can make the third altitude equation by using 2 points.

Comment: @Janno As you can read below, you don't need the third height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(1) Check the point isn't on any of those two lines (and thus those heights are to the sides of which the point is part **and** from the other two triangle's vertices);

(2) The two lines through the given vertex **and perpendicular** to the given lines are the one on which the triangle's vertices are. For example, one of them is:

$$y+4=-\frac27(x-3)$$

(3) The other two vertices are on the intersection points of the lines one which the sides of the triangle lay and the given heights (why?)

Comment: Thank you. Point 2 was the point what I was missing. Seem to forget the fundamentals of math. Thanks to it being perpendicular, this makes sense.

Comment: One problem tho, I did get 2 of the side equations, but the third one (perpendicular to the altitude drawn through the given point), now that's with what I'm having a hard time. I know that the slope of the final line is 1 (because the 3rd altitude equation is $y=-x-1$

Comment: And yet again, after posting, I think I figured this one out. Sorry... :D

Comment: Yep, I used one of the altitude equations and one of the triangle side equations to get another vertex of the triangle, got the third altitude equation to get the slope of the final side and then used the $y-y0 = k(x-x0)$ to solve it all. Thank you a lot DonAntonio!